# Reverse proxy for use with iframe

Tags: nginx, video, reverse-proxy

[Weather Observations-II](https://observeredweather.000webhostapp.com/observations-II.html)

this web page has the following link:

[Videofeed of Weather Condition](https://observeredweather.000webhostapp.com/Videofeed.html)

this page calls iframe link:

```
<iframe width-"1300" height="731" src="http://c500.duckdns.org:8889/backyard"></iframe>
```

/backyard is video camera streaming webRTC; from a Raspberry Pi, running Wyze-Bridge docker container.  Video scheme is only available as http.  This is mixed content and gets blocked.

Is it possible to use nginx reverse proxy; so the /backyard video can use https scheme?

I am using Duckdns of c500.duckdns.org; have Letsencypt certicates.  Have been unable to produce video from the iframe call.

What should the /etc/nginx/available-site/c500.duckdns.org contain?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name observeredweather.000webhostapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:443;  # Forward HTTP requests to HTTPS
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name c500.duckdns.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-3/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-3/privkey.pem;

    # Additional SSL configuration here if needed
    location / {
        # Configure your proxy settings for the HTTPS server here
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.16:8889/backyard;  # Replace with your backend server's address
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just found your edit; appreciate the help, Thank you Gerald.

Comment: Documented how to Reverse Proxy for converting http video to https video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3jfZng37w5FlpYAb9nyhD4KHh6xG7QB/view?usp=sharing